# clarification for a field extension argument

Tags: ring-theory, finite-fields, extension-field

can you help me understand the field extensions by verifying/pointing out what's wrong with this argument.

Let $F_{25} = \frac{Z_5[x]}{<x^2+2>}$.

How many subfields does $F_{25}$ have?

**Solution:** Since char($F_{25}$) = 5, then it contains the smallest subfield is $Z_5$. Then if T is a subfield by the tower law we have $2 = |F_{25}:Z_5|=|F_{25}:T||T:Z_5|$ from which we get that $|F_{25}:T|=1,2$.

If it equals $1$, then we have $1$ vector and |T| scalars and we want to be able to generate $F_{25}$ $\Rightarrow$ $T=Z_{25}$

If it equals $2$, then similarly we get $T=Z_5$.

Is that true?

Comment: The tower law, indeed, tells us that $T=F_5$ and $T=F_{25}$ are the only subfields. But, $T$ cannot be $\Bbb{Z}_{25}$ because that ring is not a field. This follows from $char(\Bbb{Z}_{25})=25$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is correct. You've correctly identified that a subfield of $\mathbf{F}_{5^2}$ must contain the prime field $\mathbf{F}_5$ and hence is an intermediate field of the extension $\mathbf{F}_{5^2}/\mathbf{F}_5$ and so must have degree $1$ or $2$ over $\mathbf{F}_5$ and equally, $\mathbf{F}_{5^2}$ must have degree $2$ or $1$ over $T$.

I would prefer to argue that $|T| = 5^{[T : \mathbf{F}_5]}$ so either $T$ has 5 elements ($T = \mathbf{F}_5$) or 25 elements ($T = \mathbf{F}_{5^2}$) but the idea you have is correct as well. However:

- you do not have $1$ vector, you have $|T|$ vectors, it is the dimension of $\mathbf{F}_{25}/T$ which is $1$
- "we want to be able to generate $\mathbf{F}_{25}$" does not explain well why $T = \mathbf{F}_{25}$